# Let $f$ have a zero at $z_0$ of multiplicity $k$. Show that the residue of $\frac{f'}{f}$ at $z_0$ is $k$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ have a zero at $z_0$ of multiplicity $k$. Show that the residue of $\frac{f'}{f}$ at $z_0$ is $k$.

I tried approaching it by saying that $h(z) = \frac{f'}{f}$ has a simple pole because $f'$ has zero of order $k-1$ and $f$ has zero of order $k$ but I don't know if that is the correct strategy to calculate residue.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** $$f(z)=(z-z_0)^kg(z)$$ where $g$ is analytic and $g(z_0)\ne0$. Now calculate $f'/f$ explicitly.